# Is there any pattern involved in the following sequence?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence, sequence

Consider the numerical sequence $$800,1600,4800,6400,12000,6400, \cdots.$$ Is there any pattern involved in this sequence? I am very curious to know that.
This puzzle is from a FlipKart Daily Quiz.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a puzzle you didn't create yourself so it is required to state where this puzzle is from. Can you please include the source of this puzzle? Thank you and happy puzzling!

Comment: This puzzle I found in flipkart daily quiz today.

Comment: Thank you! I suggested an edit that adds the source to the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is from a current competition (FlipKart).

Comment: @mathmaniac. Don't know if it is helpful but the odd index terms might follow the pattern $800n(2n-1)$ , where $n$ is the index number.

Answer (score 2):

If your three dots at the end would mean that 3 elements left then the pattern is the palindromic one. However if we don`t know how many elements are left, we cannot state this.

Comment: yes, that is the only logical answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern,

> **800(1), 2*800(1), 3*800(2), 4*800(2),  5*800*(3)** 
>   now, in the
>   end, there is 6400 which seems like the number, in the end, is
>   reduced, there is only one such number is the series, so it will be
>   very difficult to guess without options or one more number in the
>   series to know the next one. for now, **the series can have multiple
>   answers because you can put up any logic to get 6400 from 12000**. so,
>   because of that 6400 it is not possible to solve the series without
>   more information. example 
>  logic 1 ->(5*800+3*800) = 6400 
>   logic 2 -> 12000-5600 = 6400 
>  logic 3 -> 5*800*(3) - 800*7
>   
>  but the best logic is **4*800(2) = 6400**

Comment: But the sixth term is 6400 (not 800).

Comment: @hexomino yes, that is the only part to figure it out... we can just assume here he did divide or something but this will be just a guess. we can not identify reduction pattern, because there is only a one number in the pattern which gets reduced.. there is no perfect reduction logic here. so you can use any logic...